# I'm trying this simple code and I get this error

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<curses.h>
int main()
{
std::cout<<" alert \a";
getstr();
return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Expected primary expression before ')' token getstr();
```

Comment: `Int` must be completely lowercase

Comment: getstr expects a string pointer, you didn't give it an argument.

Comment: Here's the signature of the function `int getstr(char *str);`

Comment: So your telling me getstr is not a substitute for getch?

Answer (score 2):

`getstr` requires a char pointer as a parameter. This is where it will store the string from user input. As [Dampen59](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9892719/dampen59) pointed out, this is the function signature.

```
int getstr(char *str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of the function is:

```
int getstr(char *str);
```

as you read in the [ref](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_getstr.3.asp).

You are *not* passing any argument, thus you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `getstr()` without an argument, though the exception does a bad job of telling you that. I had similar problems starting out with c++. Try this:

```
int getstr(char *str);
```

Looks like a few people beat me to this answer though.